# Windows multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing

Есть сервер "всё-в-одном" на питон. Задачи разделены на процессы. Не получается управлять ими в windows. Приложение форкается,  а после этого их не возможно завершить штатно.

`setup()` кладет в `services` экземпляры `multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)`

```
def main(args=None,daemon=False):

    import signal,os

    services = []

    def start(*a):
        for proc in services:
            proc.daemon=True
            proc.start()


    def kill(*a):
        for proc in services:
            debug('terminate %s' % proc.name)
            proc.terminate()

    def wait(n=1):
        for proc in services:
            proc.join(n)

    setup(services,args=args)

    start()

    while True:
        try:
            wait()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            break

    kill()
```

С ctrl+c разобрался - ctrl+break.

При завершении главного процесса ожидаю что через секунду дети начнут завершаться. Исключение должно вызываться на `proc.join(n)` далее разрыв while и kill. Но дочерние процессы так и остаются работать.

На Линуксе завершается корректно.

Comment: *"нажатии ctrl+c"* - нажатии где?

Comment: в консольке, где же ещё?

Comment: Эти дочерние процессы приатаченны к этой консоли? А получают ли они Ctrl+C? И обрабатывают ли? Штатное завершение обычно подразумевает наличие IPC механизма для отправки команды процессору на выход. В ваших приложениях есть такой механизм?

Comment: Дочерние процессы приаттачить к консольке не получится и не надо. эвент получает родитель и делает всем терминате

Comment: Зачем IPC? просто послать  сигнал  и поймать его

Comment: Сигналы имеются на линуксе, да и то, являются атавизмом, так что использовать их без крайней надобности не следует.

Comment: Давайте еще ioctl назовем атавизмом.. ИПЦ можно порвать случайно или намеренно.

Comment: ioctl - это скорее "традиционный трешачeк", а IPC все равно наверняка придется делать в том или ином виде